# How to get notified when SFTP Remote Server is UP using Spring Boot Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

I am working on a scenario, where the SFTP remote server is down for an hour or more. How do I get notified when the remote server is up again so that I can SFTP files as soon as it is back to an active state.
Currently, I am using Spring integration sftp, and spring-boot java f/w. Are there any built-in methods I can use?

Comment: Can you ping the server?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if such a question is correct at all: the SFTP server i a passive service: you call it, no opposite. Therefore I doubt there is such a feature in any SFTP vendors like send notifications about its lifecycle.

You can ping the server periodically with a `DefaultSftpSessionFactory.getSession()`. It checks for the connection and tries to reconnect otherwise.

Another solution is to use a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` on your `SftpMessageHandler` to retry sending the file for some number of attempts with some backoff in between.

See more in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints.html#retry-advice

Comment: Thank's for ur Suggestions. As u have mentioned I was previously using  SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> defaultSessionFactory to check if session is open now i will integrate it with spring retry... Thanks for the Info..